# In Aqueduct, how do I solve the 12th puzzle in room 5?

Tags: ios, aqueduct

How do I solve the 12th puzzle in room 5? Please give the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

[image: level 5-12]

[Source website](http://ameblo.jp/iphonegames/theme-10024600670.html) (Japanese)